# Simple_form with Bootstrap: create 2 inline fields in a horizontal form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am trying to create 2 inline fields (minimum age and maximum age fields) in a generally horizontal form but nothing is working.

```
=simple_form_for([:admin, @group], :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal', :remote => true },  wrapper: :horizontal_form, wrapper_mappings: {check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, file: :horizontal_file_input, boolean: :horizontal_boolean}, ) do |f|
  =f.input :title
  =f.input :desc, :label => "Description"
  =f.input :minimum_age,:wrapper_html => { :style => 'display: inline !important' }
  =f.input :maximum_age, :wrapper_html => { :style => 'display: inline !important' }
  =f.input :include_null_birthday, as: :radio_buttons, label_html: {data: {toggle: "tooltip", title: "Some comment.", placement: "right"}}, label: "Include people with no birthday set [?]"
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but as this one is easy :

```
    <div class="button-inline">
      <%= f.input :minimum_age,:wrapper_html %>
      <%= f.input :maximum_age, :wrapper_html %>
    </div>
```

In your css :

```
    .button-inline {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
```